# Error: No Known Class method for selector 'addChild'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So, I created a new class named 'Level1Class' and I made a method named 'level1Layout'. In that method I created a SKSprite named 'level1ButtonRed' and when I set the position and try to add it by using

```
[self addChild: level1ButtonRed]
```

and it gives me the error

> `"No Known Class method for selector 'addChild'."`

```
#import "Level1Class.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation Level1Class

+(void) level1Layout{

    SKSpriteNode *level1ButtonRed;
    level1ButtonRed = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"LevelButton_Red"];
    level1ButtonRed.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild: level1ButtonRed];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "GameScene.h"

static NSString *levelButtonRed = @"levelButtonRed";

@implementation GameScene

SKSpriteNode *trans;

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    trans = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Transparent"];
     }

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        trans.position = location;

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"levelButtonRed" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node1, BOOL *stop1){
            if( [trans intersectsNode:node1]){
                [Level1Class level1Layout];
            }
        }];

    } }

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */ }

@end
```

**Level1Class.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Level1Class : NSObject

-(void) level1Layout;

@end
```

Any help??

Comment: Update your question with the actual code causing your issue.

Comment: what @rmaddy said, post code and an actual error message from the log output edit: Dude, we need CODE... not one line snippets. Do you know how to debug?

Comment: What is Level1Class a subclass of? My guess is you subclassed the wrong class.

Comment: Show more code. I suspect your call to `[self addChild:...]` is in a class method instead of an instance method.

Comment: @rmaddy, I think you're right. I was suspecting that from the "No Known Class method" error indicating he's calling it as if it were a class method rather instance method on a class.

Comment: @Young_Programmer, if you want help on these forums you'll need to learn how to post enough data for people to help you debug it. Pretend you were debugging it and post the data you'd need.

Comment: I added the code from the 'Level1Class'. @rmaddy Sorry I didn't do it before.

Comment: Change your `level1Layout` method to an instance method and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: @rmaddy - He hasn't shown us the the parent class, so there's no reason to believe that an `addChild` method exists.

Comment: **SHOW US THE CODE!!  HOW IS YOUR CLASS DECLARED??**

Comment: @rmaddy - Surely you know better by now that you can't assume *anything* when a question is so poorly documented.

Comment: Ok, I added the 'GameScene.m' file, Which is the main file i suppose.. Sorry I'm bad at this.. :/ @HotLicks

Comment: And I tried changing it to an instance and it still did not work.. Same error.. @rmaddy

Comment: You still need to show the .h for the `Level1Class` interface.

Comment: So you have no .h files that define your interfaces?

Comment: Ok, There we go, still extremely sorry lol. @rmaddy

Comment: At a guess you either intend `Level1Class` to be an `SKNode`, but you've inherited from `NSObject`, or you have an instance of `SKNode` and meant to call `addChild:` on that and not on `self`.

Comment: Level1Class has no `addChild` method, and does not inherit from a class that does.  Hence `addChild` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You send that message to `self` inside `+level1Layout`. This is a class method. Therefore `self` points to the class object. You cannot add children to class objects. You can add children to instance objects of that class.

To solve that issue create an instance first and then add the child to that instance.